# getting current GMT in matlab

Tags: matlab, date, time

How can I get the current date and time in GMT from Matlab if it is connected to Internet. I want to make a world clock which calculates time by adding time offset to current GMT.

Comment: If offline is okay, how about using the inbuild function `clock` and convert it as you want it?

Comment: From which webpage do you want to read the GMT? That would help us

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: So If I use the function 'clock' can I switch between time zones whenever I want? Actually I am syncing MATLAB with ardinuo to display time on a LCD. So will clock function help me now?

Comment: I am not reading GMT from any webpage. But how can I use GMT in MATLAB coding to switch between time zones?

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2015

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it without the internet. You can call

```
time_ms_UTC= java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
```

for the time in milliseconds. You can covert that to a more readable time and use MATLAB's [`tzoffset`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tzoffset.html) to change timezone to GMT.

**Disclaimer**: I believe this will not give you the international, atomic clock GMT, but local time. I'll leave the answer here for now.

Credit: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251275

Comment: `java.util.Date().getTimezoneOffset` will give you (in hours) what Java thinks your offset is locally, which you can use with [`clock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html) or other similar functions. The [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime-properties.html) class (R2014b+) has built-in TZ support.

Comment: In 2010b, I'm seeing `java.util.Date().getTimezoneOffset` return an offset in minutes,